# Relationship between Spark Partition and Parallelism

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing, partitioning, partition

I don't understand what you mean by more partitions in Spark, the higher the degree of parallelization.

One core(task) processes one partition, which means that it is parallelized by the number of cores.

Then, parallelism is related to the number of cores, but isn't it not related to the number of partition?

I would like to know if there is a part that works differently from the way I know it.

Answer (score 2):

Parallelism in Spark is related to both the number of cores and the number of partitions. Generally, each core in a processing cluster can run a task in parallel, and each task can process a different partition of the data.

The number of partitions affects the granularity of parallelism in Spark, i.e., the size of the workload assigned to each core. If there are many partitions, each task will have less data to process, which can increase the efficiency of parallelism but also increase communication overhead between nodes. On the other hand, if there are few partitions, each task will have more data to process, which can reduce the efficiency of parallelism but also reduce communication overhead.

Proper data partitioning is therefore essential to achieving a high degree of efficient parallelism in Spark. A balance should be sought between the number of partitions and the size of each partition, taking into account the size of the data, the processing capacity of the cluster, and the nature of the operations to be performed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).